# MS Teams Task Module opens up in mobile client but not on web and desktop

Tags: botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams

I am using deep-link to open an embedded youtube video on a task module. But when I try to open the link from my custom app on MS Teams web or desktop client it doesn't work, I get a blank screen. But when I open the same on mobile app it works.

Here is the deep link: https://teams.microsoft.com/l/task/56a53465-74fa-4b45-8b0a-ece6c9c46ac5?url=https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY&height=medium&width=medium&title=one

Any help here is appreciated, thank you.